# How can I connect a microphone to a WT32 bluetooth module?

Tags: audio, bluetooth

I have two parts which I'd like to connect, and I'm having trouble making it work well.  The first is an OEM microphone for my car, BMW part 84 31 6 93 87 62.  You can find some info about it here: http://web.comhem.se/bengt-olof.swing/mic.htm (I have no good way to verify this info.  I haven't opened the mic, but I can see there's a PCB inside it.)

The second is a bluetooth module: Bluegiga WT32 https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Wireless/Bluetooth/WT32_Datasheet-1.pdf which has audio inputs.

If I power the mic as described in the first URL above, and connect it to tip and sleeve of a PC sound input (a cheap USB device), the mic sounds great.  So the mic is working ok.

If I connect the mic to the WT32 across a pair of caps to the (left channel) inputs on the WT32, I can hear myself, but there's a background hum and I sound compressed, like I'm far away.

I've tried powering the circuit both by direct USB connection to my laptop, and to a battery.  There is no appreciable difference in audio quality.

I've already browsed the web and tried a bunch of different circuits found there, but nothing comes close to the sound quality I get from the USB device.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I've found to connect OEM BMW mic to non-BMW device is to bypass it's internal mic module directly to 3-pin socket. Don't forget to cut internal amplifier circuit.

[image: OEM BMW mic modification for imBMW device]

Comment: This seems great, but without an independent verification, keep in mind that you could be ruining the part.

Comment: I guess I'll need to pull the cover off the back to see what needs to be altered to do this.  But at this point, maybe I should just skip the OEM mic and put another part up there?

Comment: @Passerby, you can remove added connection and solder cutted line to restore the mic.

Comment: @archbishop, everything you need is shown on the photo: 1. added connection between 3-pin socket and mic 2. cutted line near added connection. This will transform active phantom-powered mic to just directional "mechanically"-filtered mic. But don't forget to swap 1st and 3rd pins of mic's cable.

I use that modified mic with the first version of Bluetooth module (based on OVC3860) for my device [imBMW](http://imbmw.net) and it works perfectly. Now I'm going to test the mic with the new version of imBMW BT module (based on WT32). I'll notify you about any results.

Comment: Any updates on the result?

Comment: @Mast, not yet.